# SqlDataSource - get data with a simple query based on session

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

I have a dropdown in my application, which should be filled with values which are based on a session variable.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
      id="SqlDataSource3"
      runat="server"
      ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
      SelectCommand="SELECT ID_SHOP
                     FROM SHOP
                     WHERE ID_SHOP_CITY = ?">
      <SelectParameters>
          <asp:SessionParameter
            Name="selectedCityId"
            SessionField="selectedCityId"
            DefaultValue="5" />
      </SelectParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

based on this example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sessionparameter.aspx

I get syntax error - invalid character.

If I change my code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
      id="SqlDataSource3"
      runat="server"
      ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
      SelectCommand="SELECT ID_SHOP
                     FROM SHOP
                     WHERE ID_SHOP_CITY = 1">
      <SelectParameters>
          <asp:SessionParameter
            Name="selectedCityId"
            SessionField="selectedCityId"
            DefaultValue="5" />
      </SelectParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and it works. However I don't need that where clause, I need to use the session variable. How can I fix it?

Comment: I think all you need to do here is change the `= 1` to `= @selectedCityId`

Comment: The other thing the example in the link does is end the sql statement with a `;`

Answer (score 2):

The example you are pointing is using **Odbc Provider**, which uses `?` for parameter. But you are using **SqlClient provider**, which expects `@ParamName` for parameter. You can check the differences here: [Using Parameters with the SqlDataSource Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You have to change your markup to this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
      id="SqlDataSource3"
      runat="server"
      ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
      SelectCommand="SELECT ID_SHOP
                     FROM SHOP
                     WHERE ID_SHOP_CITY = @selectedCityId">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter
            Name="selectedCityId"
            SessionField="selectedCityId"
            DefaultValue="5" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the difference in specifying parameters with Odbc provider vs SqlClient provider